# How to get the div before a specific div with css selector

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

There is probably a better way to do this, but I just need this to work for now before I can come up with a better solution.
Im working on a webscraping application with Python and BeautifulSoup. I need to grab a specific div, but the placement of that div changes slightly on different pages (sometimes its the 3rd, sometimes the 4th, ect). There are no class tags or id tags on the div I want, but I did notice how there was always a div directly after the one I want, and that one has a id tag. It looks something like this:

```html
<div id="main-container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div>The div I want</div>
    <div id="point"></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

So im looking for something like this:

```css
div#main-container > div:item-before(#point)
```

Is there any easy way to do this in CSS, or do I have to come up with a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Find specific `div` using `id` or `class` and call `find_previous()` to get appropriate tag

```
html="""<div id="main-container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div>The div I want</div>
    <div id="point"></div>
    <div></div>
</div>"""
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
soup.find("div",attrs={"id":"main-container"}).find("div",attrs={"id":"point"}).find_previous()
```

Output:

```
<div>The div I want</div>
```

Comment: you can also try out with `soup.select_one("div#main-container > div#point").find_previous()`

Comment: I guess this was downvoted because it doesn't use a CSS selector, but this code works, is idiomatic Beautiful Soup code, and the OP was open to other solutions. Looks like a good answer to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can access your div by nth selector in CSS file :

```
 div#main-container:nth-child(3){
   /*Your code*/
 }
```